# Calling wait() on Thread instance in java

Tags: java, multithreading

What will happen if we call wait() method on instance of Thread class.

```
Thread t1 = new MyThread();
t1.wait();
```

What will be the state of my thread t1?

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)

Answer (score 7):

It will be the same as before your call to `wait()`. `wait()` is a method of `java.lang.Object`. It waits on the intrinsic monitor associated to the object. In that case, the object is a thread, and that doesn't change what wait() does. It's pretty bizarre to use a Thread object as a monitor, though. You should use a private and final object as monitor.

Answer (score 3):

As @Tudor (and others) have mentioned, you cannot call `wait()` on an object that you aren't `synchronized` on so you would get an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.  The thread will not be affected.

```
Thread t1 = new MyThread();
// this will throw
t1.wait();
```

You most likely should be calling `t1.join()`.  This waits for the thread to finish before continuing.  However, you have not started your `Thread t1` so the join would wait forever. If the thread had already been started, then when the `Thread.run()` method finishes (either because of it returns or throws an exception), the `join()` will return.

```
Thread t1 = new MyThread();
t1.start();
// this waits for t1 to finish
t1.join();
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing out of the ordinary will happen. You will just suspend the current thread until some other thread calls `t1.notify`. You are simply using `t1` as a plain monitor.

Btw, your code will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` because you are calling `wait` outside a synchronized block.

Indeed I find java's choice of methods a bit annoying, especially regarding the thread class.

Take for instance this scenario:

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
t.sleep(1000);
```

Which thread will sleep? The current one "obviously".

Comment: If the thread was started @Tudor, then if it finished after the `wait()` then the `Thread` would be notified by the JVM.  But this is a bad pattern to use `wait()` in this manner.  `join()` is better and it solves the race condition.

Comment: Actually the given code will produce a warning by the compiler for exactly this reason. But I agree that there's no reason to allow static methods to be called through instances in Java - bad decision.

Comment: I don't see why calling a static method on an instance has any relevance to calling `wait()` on a `Thread`.

Comment: Hey Tudor, I guess you can not call sleep on an instance, It is a static function and yes, it will sleep the current thread of execution

Answer (score 1):

It's still the java.lang.Object's [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) you're calling, so only the current thread will wait (assuming you're holding the objects monitor, otherwise an IllegalMonitorStateException will be thrown).

Answer (score 1):

To add something that has so far not been said: Actually something "out of the ordinary" will or at least can happen when you call wait on a thread object.

That is because `Thread` internally waits on `this` internally and obviously that leads to interesting results to say the least.

Comment: That only happens when you call `join()` right @Voo?  What other times?  It does call `notify()` internally of course.

Comment: @Gray I think so but not 100% sure. And why knows if `notify` is only called in case the thread has already joined? Lots of variables and implementation details I wouldn't want to rely on, considering that waiting on `this` can be considered a bad practice anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer java doc from java.lang.Thread#join(long)：

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

If you use wait on Thread instances, then As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. you will get confusing behavior which is hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Thread#wait` method. `wait` is inherited from `Object` and is used for synchronization. So unless you have `synchronized(t1)` first, you will just get an illegal monitor exception.

`t1.wait` will **NOT WAIT FOR THE THREAD TO FINISH**. It waits for a lock put on the thread object by another thread.